# model-view-controller architecture best practices from scratch

Tags: c#, java, model-view-controller

I need to understand the best practices of MVC architecture implementation. I'm a Java and C# programmer. I know the basic of MVC. But i'm sorta confused on how to implement it. I know how to make a simple MVC based calculator. But here's the thing.

I wanted to make a simple database editor application using MVC. Should I construct a model and controller for every rows (objects) of the table? If so, how about the view of every objects? How do i handle them being deleted, updated, and inserted. And should I make the model and controller for the editor which is also a view?

Comment: See also [A Swing Architecture Overview](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/architecture/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, if you are comfortable with Java try the Spring MVC. There are a lot of tutorial regarding this. If you are much more confident in C# try ASP .NET MVC 3. I will prefer the later one as in this case you have to deal with less configuration.

Now I will answer your question one by one.

At first create a model for every table in your database. Actually these models (which are nothing but classes) when instantiated are nothing but an individual row of the respective table. Your ORM (object relational mapping) tool (For java you can use hibernate, for c#.net you can use entity framework) will provide you specific methods (save(object), add(object), delete(object)) for updating the database

Now each controller should work with a specific model (Here I am ignoring the complexities of using multiple models.). But it may generate numerous views. By clicking a link in your view page you actually invoke the related method in the controller. The controller than binds the Data (if any) with the specific view realted to that link and then the view is rendered. So for deleting a row there should be a method named delete() (you may name it anything you want, so dont be confused) in your controller. When you want to delete a row invoke that method and inside the method remove that row by using something like delete(object) (these methods will be provided by your ORM) and then return another view. The same thing is applied for adding and updating data. But each method may generate different views. Its upto you that which view you return in each of these methods.

I hope the answer helps you. Cheers !!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know there are some framework that can handle this. But I wanna know how it does that. I want to learn it from scratch so that i could understand it perfectly. Lemme rephrase this, so i do have to construct many models (objects) that represent each rows of the table? And there is only one controller that controls the collection of those models? And there is also only one view that shows the values?

Comment: Suppose you are developing a student database application. So there will be a table for student's information. Create a model for student. This model (class will contain some attributes like name, year, session etc.) So when you want to add a student you have instantiate this model class that is create an object and simply add it to the database. So yes actually you can consider each row of your database as an individual object.

Comment: Now write a controller for this model class. If I was wrtiting the code I would named it StudentController. Write a method named Index inside it. Now when the application will begin it will obviously display a homepage. For that write a HomeController. You have to write it in your configuration that which controller will be loaded at startup. Now inside that HomeController create a method named index and return a view from there. Now in that view place a link to see the student details page. By clicking the link invoke the Index method of the StudentController

Comment: You may be confused how to return the view from the method. Actually you should try it by using some good IDEs. Just by right clicking inside the method a good IDE should provide you an option to return a method. And later it will also provide you the option to customize the view.

Comment: Now inside that Index method of the StudentController return a view which will show all the student details. I that view also place some link named Delete, Create, Update etc. Now write some more methods in StudentController named Delete, Create etc. Now from those links invoke these methods. Inside these methods return the views to create and delete the data (actually adding/deleting an object of the Student model). Now you can see that this Controller is dealing with only one model but it is producing different views depending on user action

Comment: There may be complex scenarios when you may need to handle with multiple models from one controller which obviously has some solutions. But for this instance try to keep it simple. As I suggested in my post for less configuration issues try asp.net mvc 3 and entity framework (though its my personal opinion). And start coding, because without it the whole process will always remain foggy. And finally if my answer really helped you can you please mark it as accepted :). Cheers

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sorry, but I'm still confused about the view. Just to make this clear, I'm not trying to develop a web application. Asp.Net MVC is a web application framework right? Or can it be used for a desktop application as well? And I'm trying build it from scratch. Should there be a class that holds the collection of the objects (rows)? Does the StudentController control each objects, or should I instantiate the controller for each objects?

Comment: And the view. I thought the view is the class that holds the user interface, i don't know how to return it. I mean technically i do know how to return a class. But, i don't know the right way to do that. Should i always return a panel/datagrid(table) and replace the existing panel/datagrid with the new one? Some of the examples i've seen tell me that i should add a reference to the view class and the model class to the controller so that it can manipulate both sides. And it never returns a view.

Comment: Firstly, you can't use asp.net mvc 3 in your desktop application. Secondly,no you will not require that sort of class. Just declare one class which represent a row of the student table. Now as you are developing desktop application I am afraid that you have to write the  Data access layer code by yourself . Create another class name StudentRepository in your project. In your StudentController keep a reference to it. Now inside the StudentRepository write some methods to retieve your data using your ORM tool. For example, for getting all the rows of the table you may write a method named getAll

Comment: Now inside the Index method of your controller you may use a list<Student> to get all the rows by using that method (getAll) in StudentRepository. By doing so you are actually separating your application layers. Thirdly, yes a view is nothing but a representation of UI. Now in that case you may write classes that extends panel or something like that. For showing all the student data You may write a class named AllStudentsDetails whose constructor will receive that list of students. Then upon the specific action replace your present panel with this panel.

Comment: For adding a student you may write another class extending a panel which will provide a form. Clicking a submit button make it invoke a method written inside your controller. That method will again use the add method written inside your repository to add that data. This is more or less my concept about using mvc in desktop apllication. Though i have not used it earlier.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, so basically the repository provides all data, and it also manipulates those right? How do i make the ORM tool myself? How does it work? Sorry, I asked a lot. I really want to master this. I promise I will choose your post as an accepted answer. Well, also since no one else posted a relevant answer.

Comment: Yes that's actually the function of repository. Start digging some tutorials regarding ORMs like hibernate and entity framework. They are comparativel easy to use. And for mastering these things what you need is practicing. I think we should end this discussion right here. Best of luck with your MVC life

Comment: Well, okay, if you say so. Actually I want to learn more about ORM from you. I don't wanna use ORM tool, just want to learn how it works and make one for myself from scratch. But anyway, thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the [Java Persistence API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API), consider using a [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Token*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) in your [`TableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).